# how to split phone line for internet without using a splitter?

Tags: wiring, receptacle, socket, telephone, internet

ISP sent a technician to fix dropout issues, he split the phone line wires into two, one taped into the bare wire end of a normal splitter, the other into an unused  bare end of phone cable, and then in order to get phone to work alongside ADSL, the phone cable plugs into the splitter, still following? Here's a pic of what he did:

[image]

As you can see it hangs from under the wall plate because it bypasses the phone socket completely. I don't know why he did this but was adamant it was proper.

Anyway to fix it?, because it doesn't look right. People use splitters by plugging it into the socket like I used to, not by tapping wires and physically splitting them.

Its ADSL pppoe line, and I really had serious problems like dropout every half hour. O haven't gotten a chance to test what he did I doubt it solved it because the workaround o see is just same as adding a splitter, but its so strange.

Update: what he did didn't fix my initial dropout problem.

Comment: Looks like crap to me. I would at least made the connections in the wall. Telecommunications and phone don't require a box like power circuits do.

Comment: Is that a splitter or an ADSL filter?  They look pretty much the same, but there is a big difference.  Either way that tech did a horrible hack job.

Comment: He said this would do, and wasn't keen on much else. I'm used to this, it's how people work here. It's why half of the power outlets here are damaged. It's an ADSL splitter I guess, used for modem and phone. I don't know what to do, should I just get two phone sockets and rewire while making sure 2 wires go to each? That way it's "split"? Or does it need an actual whole house splitter?

Comment: The dropout issue is still occurring, will call them again and hope they try to do something.

Comment: Some modern DSL routers provide a built-in splitter. If that is the case, the external splitter would not be neccesary and might lead to a semifunctional connection.